# How to specify TCL procedure argument types

Tags: tcl

Are there any standard ways to specify expected TCL procedure argument “types” (in a manner that can easily be parsed by code), either in code, in comments, external documentation, etc.?

e.g., types of arguments include:

- expression (i.e. evaluable by `expr`)
- command(s) (i.e. evaluable by `eval`)
- number
- integer
- variable name (potentially a variable with a value of specific type like dict, list, array, etc.)
- regex
- glob
- choice from a set of specific strings
- etc.

e.g.: The first argument to the `if` command should be an expression, whose value after being evaluated is read as a boolean.

The next argument to `if` is an optional literal `then`, followed by a command / command block that is evaluated if the first argument was true.

etc.

I know that everything in TCL is a string, but some strings are valid booleans & some are not, some are valid integers & some are not, some are valid expressions & some are not, etc.

Comment: Short answer is "no". Because it's a short answer I'm leaving it as a comment. Longer answer is that all arguments in tcl has only one type: string. Tcl has no other types that can be passed as arguments (that's why you can't pass arrays directly). So what does the string "look" like? That's more a human problem than a tcl problem.

Comment: I know that everything in TCL is a string, but there could be a way to specify what an argument’s string is expected to conform to. Like a JavaDoc syntax comment that accepts a value from a list of known types, or that accepts TCL code in the comment that could be parsed, like `string is boolean`. Just because it can’t be specified at the level that the standard TCL interpreter can use doesn’t mean the information cannot be specified via other means.

Comment: You asked for a standard way. The answer is no. You can invent your own way though. You can look at tcldoc (https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tcldoc) however instead of types it documents the parameter's description (eg. instead of "string" or "number" it documents "path to a file on disk" or "limit recursion depth"). I've implemented my own named paramater functionality (https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/optproc) - while it has nothing to do with type it is kind of related in that I implemented my own custom proc function.

Comment: When I said standard, I didn’t mean to restrict the options to core TCL. e.g., if someone asked “is there a standard Java library for immutable collections”, I’d point them to Guava. It’s likely there is no standard way of expressing this info for TCL, but I just wanted to clarify what I meant by standard.

Comment: I know. When I say "standard" I mean what a lot of people use. They don't. If you program in Tcl long enough you'll find that your programs are surprisingly maintainable even without types or type hints. It gives you a whole new perspective on types vs function composition & good naming conventions.

Comment: Is there a standard proc that indicates whether a string is a valid expression? A valid Tcl command/commands? I know I can write my own, but I’d prefer to use standard procs.

Comment: You might find [tepam](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/tepam/tepam_introduction.md) from tcllib useful.

Answer (score 0):

In general, no, there isn't such a way.

If you want to enforce arguments being of a certain type, you need to put some code at the beginning of the procedure to enforce that. You might find [`string is type -strict`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm) to be useful:

```
proc takesAnInteger {arg} {
    if {![string is integer -strict $arg]} {
        return -code error "argument '$arg' is not an integer"
    }
    puts [expr {2 * $arg + 3}]
}
```

A shorthand that some people use is to ensure that the first operation in the procedure is one that itself enforces a type, so `expr {1 << $arg}` forces integer-ness, `expr {1 * $arg}` forces numeric-ness, `expr {! $arg}` forces boolean-ness, `llength $arg` forces list-ness, etc. The downside of that is that it doesn't provide a perfect error message. We have [considered doing something better](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/tip/480.md) for a subset of types, but that's not been merged.

Comment: Could you add `expression` & `tcl` (or `block`, or `script`, etc.) types to specify that an argument should be parsable by `expr` & `eval`, respectively? They would be very helpful for IDEs to know how to handle braced strings, parse them for errors, etc.